# What is the cheapest way to go from Poland to Lyon (France)?

Tags: air-travel, france, international-travel, transportation, poland

I would like to travel by plane or by bus.

Comment: From where in Poland?

Comment: areas with strong emigration or diaspora towards the north-west (e.g. balkans and southern italy) usually have a breadth of informal private buses that do the trips, and the low income people usually use those. 
This may not be the case for Poland, also without precise info it can't be determined if there is a very cheap low-cost flight that could be worth it over the bus. 
But you haven't stated how much luggage you have either, this can be a deal-breaker when it comes to low-cost flight. 
http://www.eurolines.fr has buses for 80€, low-cost flights cost about the same... depends on luggage

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

- Low cost flights if you can book early
- Buses whenever: eurolines